# add_action uses 'echo' add_filter uses 'return', why?

Tags: filters, actions

An `add_action` will only give content back if you call `echo` in the function and does nothing when using `return`, why?

**WORKS**:

```
add_action( 'rss2_item', 'custom_enclosure' );
function custom_enclosure() {
  global $post;    
  $output  = 'Hello World';    
  echo $output;
};
```

**DOES NOT WORK:**

```
add_action( 'rss2_item', 'custom_enclosure' );
function custom_enclosure() {
  global $post;    
  $output  = 'Hello World';    
  return $output;
};
```

With `add_filter` one needs to use `return`, but `echo` also works?!?!

```
function insert_post_related($content) {
  $content = "Hello World";
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','insert_post_related');
```

It confuses the f*#& out of me and I have wasted 4 hours right now because I used `return` on an `add_action` instead of `echo`. For `add_filter` one can use both `return` or `echo`, why is that?

What is the convention here?

Comment: Is this the reason? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48756/whats-worth-using-add-action-when-we-can-simply-use-add-filter

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer is the reason.

Comment: Now that is a freakin HACK!